# What if we don't specify validation_data in keras model.fit ( )?

Tags: keras

The keras documentation (Sequential model) specifies the validation data as: Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data.

If we do not specify the validation data, will it affect our output?

Comment: What output are you talking about?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro The loss and accuracy of the neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the loss or accuracy of the network would not change if you did not provide validation data.

The only use of validation data is to check if the model is overfitting, Keras does not make such decisions, a human looking at the `loss` and `val_loss` would make that decision.

Answer (score 2):

No it would not, it would just provide you with extra data like the loss and val_loss. This will help you with improving your model without giving it access to your final test data.